# Very slow download from live server

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, asp.net-mvc-5

Here is my controller...

```
public ActionResult RequestImage(string url, int width, int height)
{
    Stream stream = fileService.Request(url, width, height);

    return new FileStreamResult(stream, "image/jpg");
}
```

The file service...

```
public Stream Request(string url, int width, int height)
{

    var request = new S3StorageRequest(url, null, null);

    var stream = s3Service.Request(request);

    var outputStream = new MemoryStream();

    var settings = $"maxwidth={width}";

    if (height > 0)
    {
        settings = string.Concat(settings, $"&maxheight={height}");
    }

    imageResizer.Build(stream, outputStream, settings);

    stream.Dispose();

    outputStream.Position = 0;

    return outputStream;
}
```

S3 request...

```
public Stream Request(S3StorageRequest s3Request)
{
    GetObjectRequest request = new GetObjectRequest { BucketName = bucketName };

    request.Key = s3Request.Path;

    GetObjectResponse response = S3Client.GetObject(request);

    return response.ResponseStream;
}
```

When I run this locally (which is still downloading from S3 over the internet), the S3 request takes around 130ms (as low as 78ms).

The images resizing takes around 50ms.

Here is the request according to the browser...

[image]

On the live server, this is what the browser says...

[image]

Its a t2.micro instance, my Windows instance is running via Parallels on a 2.4Gz i5. Any ideas what it's doing for 2s? The TTFB can go down to around 854ms.

Without the image resizing and download, its about 450ms. So the image resizing or the file response seems to be slow.

Comment: A t2.micro is pretty small but I still would expect better performance. Have you tried it on a larger instance type just to see?

Comment: I've tried t2.large and it didn't seem to make much difference.

Comment: Think I will pre-generate thumbnails. There are only three iPhone screen sizes. But I would love some insight into how this can be happening.

Comment: If that helps please post an update. I'm interested to know if it does or if there's something else.